# How to verify Cauchy's theorem for the following equation $f ( z ) = z ^2$ evaluated around a circular contour

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

Could someone please give me some help with the following question to verify Cauchy's theoreom for the following equation $f ( z ) = z ^2$  evaluated  around the circular contour  $  Re^{iθ}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: express the contour integral $\oint_\Gamma f(z)\; dz$ as an ordinary integral using $z = R e^{i\theta}$, $dz = iR e^{i\theta} \; d\theta$, $\theta = 0 \ldots 2\pi$.